# iOS code coverage report contains files that shouldn't be in there

Tags: ios, xcode, llvm, code-coverage, xcrun

I have an Xcode project with two targets - the main target where the source code lives (let's call it CoolApp), and a test target for the unit tests (let's call it CoolAppTests). I also have a Git commit hook that ensures I can't commit a change if the total line coverage of the project falls below a certain percentage.

The problem is that the coverage report contains not only the files in CoolApp, but also the files in CoolAppTests. As a result, when I add a new test file, the total line coverage of the project might actually go *down*, which makes the commit hook kind of useless.

To generate the coverage report, I go through the following steps:

```
xcodebuild test \
   -project "CoolApp.xcodeproj" \
   -scheme "CoolAppTests" \
   -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=10.0" \
   -configuration Debug \
   -enableCodeCoverage YES
```

Then I get the DerivedData for CoolAppTests by looking up the TEMP_ROOT directory in the build settings (xcodebuild -target CoolAppTests -showBuildSettings). From there, I get the /CodeCoverage/Coverage.profdata, and the binary located at /CodeCoverage/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CoolAppTests.xctest/CoolAppTests.

```
PROFDATA=.../CodeCoverage/Coverage.profdata
BINARY=.../CodeCoverage/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CoolAppTests.xctest/CoolAppTests
```

Finally, I generate the report and capture its output:

```
xcrun llvm-cov report -instr-profile "${PROFDATA}" "${BINARY}"
```

At that point, as indicated earlier, the report contains files from both CoolApp and CoolAppTests.

Is there any way to filter out what goes in the report so it only has the files of my main target - CoolApp - and *not* the files from my test target CoolAppTests?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. I was able to show the report on a framework of my by executing:

```
xcrun llvm-cov report -instr-profile Coverage.profdata 
    Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/StoryTeller.framework/StoryTeller
```

Notice I specified the path to the framework. This showed me the framework classes only. To display the coverage of the tests I had to use this:

```
xcrun llvm-cov report -instr-profile Coverage.profdata
    Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/StoryTellerTests.xctest/StoryTellerTests
```

To double check this I went into the derived data for a Swift app I'm working on and executed this:

```
xcrun llvm-cov report -instr-profile Coverage.profdata 
    Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxxxx.app/xxxxxx
```

Again I was only shown the coverage for the classes in the app.

I'm guess that what is going on with your code is that when you built the test target, you told it to compile all your app classes as well as your test classes. Therefore the test target will regard them as part of the test code. It's something that I've often seen developers do. Your test target should have the app in it's Target Dependencies, but it does not need to compile or include the classes again, even if only running unit tests. The app classes will automatically be available to it for testing purposes.

Comment: A few questions: 1) do you have coverage enabled for your framework target, your test target, or both; 2) would this still work if the output of the build is a static library rather than a framework/app?

Comment: I have enabled coverage support on all targets (I think this is the default) and gather coverage data on in the test settings of the scheme. As for a static library. Not sure. But I would assume it would be the same. Do you have your app classes included in the Compile Sources build phase? If so, please remove them and try again.